# Carousel with overlay text bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4, carousel, navbar, web-frontend

I am working on a project with Bootstrap 4. I want to make a navbar. but I did not get it. I've searched and found a few bootstrap 3 code. I tried these codes but I did not get results. I want to do the same as the navbar on this link, but with bootstrap 4. I am trying to add navbar. I did not see it. Would you help me to make a navbar like this link. I want the carousel to be full screen, I could just do it. sorry for my bad language.(responsive)

this link: http://cato3000.com/carousel-foreground-example/

```css
.carousel-item {
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 300px;
  background: no-repeat center center scroll;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
          <div class="carousel-item active" style="background-image: url('https://preview.ibb.co/mrJAZe/carousel.jpg')">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
              <h3>First Slide</h3>
              <p>This is a description for the first slide.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('http://www.albetekstil.com.tr/img/s1.jpg')">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
              <h3>Second Slide</h3>
              <p>This is a description for the second slide.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('http://www.faertekstil.com/tr/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/tekstil-sirketi2.jpg')">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
              <h3>Third Slide</h3>
              <p>This is a description for the third slide.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </header>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure thing.

This is easy to do. Take a look at the Carousel example page on their website.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/examples/

From there all you need to do is fix the main section/carousel(this should have a role tag called main) to the top and make the z-index on the navbar to be in front of the carousel (which I believe is about 1090 by the standard)

Also changing the width of the navbar is as simple as changing either the style or putting it in a container.

Have a go with that and let us know if you run into any troubles.

Comment: I did it. But the navbar not on the carousel. Navbar is on bottom. I want  to on top and I want some space. Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/s5h0vkgu/2/ but it happened-->>>>> https://jsfiddle.net/s5h0vkgu/5/ How can i do it?

Comment: The order was a little off(remember that the navbar should be at the top if you want it to show there) and sections had styles that I removed. But apart from that, it was pretty good. Is this what you are after? https://jsfiddle.net/s5h0vkgu/21/

Comment: i really appreciate what you are doing. You’re a great help. Thank you!!

Comment: No worries. Here to help :)